# How to create only one file per loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to save incoming serial data to a file with a date/time stamp as the file name, however each time the minute changes I get a new file with the next stamp and containing the data where the previous file left off. Is there a way to keep python from starting a new file or to only make the single date/time stamped file for this loop?

```
while
~~   
    filename = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open(filename.strftime("%d %B %Y %H %M")+".txt", 'a') as f:                            
        f.writelines([data, '\n'])
```

Comment: yes. by saving the first file name in global variable (above the while loop), `file_name=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d %B %Y %H %M")+".txt"` , and in the while loop your expression becomes,`with open(file_name,'a') as fp:....`

Comment: Brilliant, works great now!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file once, outside the loop:

```
filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d %B %Y %H %M")+".txt"
with open(filename, 'a') as f:                            
    while ...
        f.writelines([data, '\n'])
```

This is more efficient than opening and closing it on every loop iteration.